# How to decode DUKPT CBC mode in Java?

Tags: swipe, dukpt

I can't decode the DUKPT swipe Data, I'm trying using differers examples but the credit card information is encoded yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Maybe you should post some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide some code samples - without them people will not be able to give you the answer you are looking for. I also suggest that you read the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. BTW, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I had a headache trying of decoding the swipe information:

This example can help you to do it:

To Download the Java Example here: https://github.com/ricardojava/mobile/tree/master/TEST_GATE2all/src/com/bbpos
To Modify the file: https://github.com/ricardojava/mobile/blob/master/TEST_GATE2all/src/com/bbpos/SimpleMain.java

String bdk = "0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210";
String ksn = "00000232100117e00027";
String tk1 = "de8bfe769dca885cf3cc312135fe2cccfacf176235f4bdee773d1865334315ed2aefcab613f1884b5d63051703d5a0e2bd5d1988eeabe641bd5d1988eeabe641";

```
   String key = DUKPTServer.GetDataKey(ksn, bdk);
```

String decryptedTLV = TripleDES.decrypt_CBC(tk1, key);

```
byte[] s = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(decryptedTLV);

    System.out.println(new String(s));
```

}
I hope it can help you!........